# visualize csv elements with a delay in between

Tags: javascript, csv, d3.js

I have a csv file. I want to visualize elements in the file with a one second delay between each element. I tried following code but all the records elements visualize without a delay.(here i have replaces visualization with colsole.log())

```
<script> 
  d3.csv("csv/AssassinsCreedOnlyLocation.csv",function(capitalsArray){
   var noOfTweets = capitalsArray.length;
   for(i=0; i<noOfTweets;i++){
    console.log(capitalsArray[i].Lat+" "+capitalsArray[i].Long);
    setTimeout(function(){
      console.log("......");
    },5000);
   }

  });

</script>
```

Comment: `setTimeout` isn't a sleep, it's a delayed execution. Right now you're displaying every capital immediately, and as much `.....` 5 seconds after, right? Maybe you could use a recursive function which would finish by recursing with a `setTimeout`

Comment: yes. that's what exactly happened. can you please give a sample code for the purpose? I tried many methods but nothing works.. thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An iterative approach using `setTimeout` would have to calculate in how much time each element of the array needs to be displayed and set a delayed execution for each of them, i.e. :

```
for(i=0; i<noOfTweets;i++){
    setTimeout(
        function() {
            console.log(capitalsArray[i].Lat+" "+capitalsArray[i].Long);
        }, 
        5000 * i
    );
}
```

The problem with that approach is that it can create a great amount of timers, which I can't think is a good idea.

While the recursive approach using `setTimeout` I mentionned in the comments would be possible, the more popular and easier alternative is to rely on [`setInterval`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setInterval) instead of `setTimer` :

```
var i = 0;
var intervalId = setInterval(
    function() {
        if (i == capitalsArray.length) {
            clearInterval(intervalId); // stops executing once we've browsed through the array
        } else {
            console.log(capitalsArray[i].Lat+" "+capitalsArray[i].Long);
            i++;
        }
    },
    5000
);
```